# Implementing push notifications for both iOS and Android for Angular PWA project

Tags: c#, android, ios, angular, push

I have successfully adapted Android push notifications using Angular's service-worker lib:

**package json:**

```
"@angular/service-worker": "~12.2.16"
```

**import:**

```
import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker';
```

**frontend code:**

```
public subscribe() {
// my endpoint
this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseURL}/backgroundPush/subscriptions/key`, { responseType: 'text' })
.subscribe(publicKey => {
  this.swPush.requestSubscription({
    serverPublicKey: publicKey
  }).then((subscription) => {
      this.endpoint = subscription.endpoint;
      //my endpoint
      this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseURL}/backgroundPush/subscriptions/add`, subscription).subscribe(() => {
       },
        error => this.handleSubscriptionFailure(error))
    })
    .catch((error) => this.handleSubscriptionFailure(error));
},
  error => this.handleSubscriptionFailure(error));
```

}

**on backend side I use c# and following lib to deliver push messages:**

```
 <PackageReference Include="Lib.Net.Http.WebPush" Version="3.2.1" />
```

**and it works perfectly to deliver messages for Android devices!**

However, this solution doesn't work on iOS devices.
I've got following error in console when someone tries to subscribe for push messages:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating t.pushManager)
```

1. What are the possibilities to extend push notifications to make them work on iOS/Safari taking into account that I already use service-worker?
2. What else would you suggest instead of service-worker and why?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions at once. Focus on one problem and try to describe it well. Isn't the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating t.pushManager)` the actual problem? Where does it occur? (What is `t.pushManager`?)

Comment: I've limited it to 2 questions now. 

I do not use t.pushManager explicitly. I have found pushManager in service-worker.d.ts file, which can be found under node_modules/@angular/service-worker/service-worker.d.ts - and It is member of SwPush class which I use.

Answer (score 0):

According to this source:

https://pushalert.co/blog/ios-web-push-notifications-safari-available/

**It is not possible to send web-push notifications using service worker at the moment**, but will be possible in the next year:

---

*Update - June 2022:*

Apple has now confirmed at WWDC 2022, that it will be adding web push notifications support to Safari on iOS in Early 2023 with iOS 16. **You can expect all browsers on iPhones and iPads to support web push notifications early next year.**

*Update - February 2022:*

Apple has finally added experimental web push support to Safari on iOS and other browsers like Chrome and Firefox. **So we should see Web Push Notifications on iPhones and iPads by end of 2022 – more details here.**

Answer (score 0):

Answering the specific questions you asked.

**1. What are the possibilities to extend push notifications to make them work on iOS/Safari taking into account that I already use service-worker?**

In iOS Safari, you can't (As of now). But Apple confirmed that this feature will be available with an update to iOS16 in 2023 - https://engagespot.co/blog/send-web-push-notification-ios-safari

**2. What else would you suggest instead of service-worker and why?**
Nothing else works for web push notifications. You need to wait till web push is available in iOS.